# Openntpd doesn't start on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, apparmor, ntp

I have a problem after installing Openntpd on Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64 (it can happen on other version). The service openntp doesn't want to start in logs i see:

```
Apr 14 12:00:00 my-host kernel: [24.6] type=1400 audit(1.2:1): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/etc/openntpd/ntpd.conf" pid=1526 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of the reader:

The problem stems from a previous install of package `ntp`.  When `ntp` is replaced by `openntpd`, it leaves some config files around, one of this is `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd`.  This then blocks `openntpd` from running properly.  `ntp` is normally installed by default, so this usually always happens after installing `openntpd` when `apparmor` is active.

The solution is:

```
sudo apt-get purge ntp
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
sudo /etc/init.d/openntpd restart
```

If you like to use `apparmor` with `openntpd` (you probably switched to `openntpd` to have something more secure, right?), here is what I have added as `/etc/apparmor.d/openntpd` (I do not know if this is complete.  It works at my side so far):

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor

#include <tunables/global>

/usr/sbin/ntpd {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>
  #include <abstractions/user-tmp>

  /etc/openntpd/ntpd.conf r,
  /var/lib/openntpd/run/ntpd.sock rw,
  /var/lib/openntpd/db/ntpd.drift rw,

  capability sys_time,
  capability sys_nice,
  capability sys_chroot,
  capability setgid,
  capability setuid,
  capability kill,
}
```

**Why not "fix" `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd` for `openntpd`?**

Because `ntp` is a resource monster.  It needs trainloads of permissions, which are not needed for `openntpd`.  The right thing to do is to restrict `openntpd` to what it needs, not what `ntp` needs.

BTW: The probably best solution would be to have Canonical add a proper `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd` to package `openntpd`, which then overrides the left over config from `ntp`.  One can consider this a bug in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with apparmor and ntpd (not openntpd) when openntpd installed they removed default package ntpd but didn't remove/edit apparmor rules `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd` You can delete rules or just fix it by adding a lines `/etc/openntpd/ntpd.conf r,` and `/{,var/}lib/openntpd/run/ntpd.sock rwl,` after line `/etc/ntp.conf r,` After that restart apparmor and start openntpd.

```
sudo service apparmor restart
sudo service openntpd start
```

Also instead of adding line directly to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd` you can add it to site specific file `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.ntpd`